# Does maven automatically pack jar files into war file?

Tags: java, apache, maven

I used somebody source code, and jar libraries thereof. When I build the war file upload to my server, I often encounter NoClassDefFound errors because the libraries are not in the artifact. I learned (or overheard somewhere) that maven will automatically pack everything needed into the war files (depending on running goal). Is it true so?

I need to know so that I invest time to learn maven. If so, any quick & dirty tutorials? :), thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is more dirty than quick. (Insert vulgarities here.)

[Maven in Five Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) is the quickest, dirtiest there is.

Maven packages transitive dependencies into the war file unless configured to do otherwise.